# DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint error ef core

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have entity:

```
public class InitiativeItem
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public InitiativeItem Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And Fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<InitiativeItem>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Parent)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.ParentId)
                .IsRequired(false);
```

When I'm trying to delete this entity I get error:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_InitiativeItems_InitiativeItems_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.InitiativeItems", column 'ParentId'.
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I resolve my issue?

Comment: maybe the `entity` that you are trying to delete is a parent of some of your `entities`?

Comment: I get the same error, In my local Pc with local sql server 2016 + but in my test environment with sql 2014 I'm not getting the error. are you found any solution?